# ParametricPlot with condition for parameters

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

For example

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[x] - y, Cos[y] - x}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

gives

[image]

What should I do to impose `x^2+y^2==2` (actually it could be a more complicated function) and only plot for those parameters that satisfy that condition? `Mesh` didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
 Quiet @ ParametricPlot[{Sin[x] - y, Cos[y] - x} , {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π},  
   BoundaryStyle -> Dotted, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.25, LightBlue], 
   MeshStyle -> Opacity[1, Red], 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3^+ #4^2 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{2}}]
```

[image]

Use `BoundaryStyle -> None` and `PlotStyle -> None` to hide the surface and its boundary.